# Implementing SHA1-HMAC with Python

Tags: python, sha1, hmac

I am implementing SHA1-HMAC generation for python (v 3.7) to be able to create HMAC code.

I have used an [online generator to create SHA1-HMAC](https://www.freeformatter.com/hmac-generator.html) with the following data:

- string: `'123'`
- Secret Key: `'secret'`
- Digest algorithm: `SHA1`

I am getting this result:

```
b14e92eb17f6b78ec5a205ee0e1ab220fb7f86d7
```

However when I try to do this same with Python I am getting different results which are wrong.

```
import hashlib
import hmac
import base64

def make_digest(message, key):
    key = bytes(key, 'UTF-8')
    message = bytes(message, 'UTF-8')

    digester = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha1)
    signature1 = digester.digest()

    signature2 = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(signature1)    
    return str(signature2, 'UTF-8')


result = make_digest('123', 'secret')
print(result)
```

This code gives result:

```
sU6S6xf2t47FogXuDhqyIPt_htc=
```

What could be wrong with this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should not use Base64 here. The site you link to gives you the *hex values* of the digest bytes. Use the [`HMAC.hexdigest()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.HMAC.hexdigest) to get the same value in hex in Python:

```
>>> key = b'secret'
>>> message = b'123'
>>> digester = hmac.new(key, message, hashlib.sha1)
>>> digester.hexdigest()
'b14e92eb17f6b78ec5a205ee0e1ab220fb7f86d7'
```

put differently, your code outputs the correct value, but as Base64-encoded data:

```
>>> digester.digest()
b'\xb1N\x92\xeb\x17\xf6\xb7\x8e\xc5\xa2\x05\xee\x0e\x1a\xb2 \xfb\x7f\x86\xd7'
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(digester.digest())
b'sU6S6xf2t47FogXuDhqyIPt_htc='
```

and the value you generated online contains the exact same bytes as the hex digest, so we can generate the same base64 output for that:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('b14e92eb17f6b78ec5a205ee0e1ab220fb7f86d7')
b'\xb1N\x92\xeb\x17\xf6\xb7\x8e\xc5\xa2\x05\xee\x0e\x1a\xb2 \xfb\x7f\x86\xd7'
>>> base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes.fromhex('b14e92eb17f6b78ec5a205ee0e1ab220fb7f86d7'))
b'sU6S6xf2t47FogXuDhqyIPt_htc='
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation. It was really helpful.